# Drawing on canvas does not happen in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to make a canvas of squers and rectangles that appear randomly, the amount of them is the users choice. after they input the numbers of eace of them, press a button-it should appear on the canvas. in my code it does not happen, and i cant understand why! making me crazy here. I'm obviously missing something here, and i guess its a very stupid thing.

```js
function draw() {
  var drawing = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var context = drawing.getContext("2d");
  saveImage();
}


//save the user input to use it later 
var numOfRect = parseInt(document.getElementById("inSquer").value);
var numOfCirc = parseInt(document.getElementById("inCircle").value);


//This function will draw on the canvas
function paint(numOfRect, numOfCirc) {
  for (var makeIt = 0; makeIt < numOfRect; makeIt++) {
    makeRect(drawing, context);
    makeCircle(drawing, context);
  }
}


//This function draw the circles
function makeCircle(drawing, context) {
  var radius = Math.floor(Math.random() * 80);
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height);

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.fillStyle = "blue";
  context.fill();
}


//This function draw the squers
function makeRect(drawing, context) {

  var w = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);

  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height);
  context.fillStyle = "yellow";
  context.fillRect(x, y, w, w);
}

//function to save the canvas as an image
function saveImage() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  canvas.onclick = function() {
    window.location = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  };
}
```

```css
#canvas {
  margin-left: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="js.js">
  </script>
  <link href="design.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body onload="draw()">

  <canvas id="canvas" width="1200" height="750"></canvas>
  </br>
  </br>
  <span>
    How many Circles do you want?
    <input id="inCircle"></input>
    </span>
  </br>
  How many Squers do you want?
  <input id="inSquer"></input>
  </br>

  <button id="creat" onclick="paint()">Creat My Work</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`paint(numOfRect, numOfCirc)` wants 2 parameters, but `<button id="creat" onclick="paint()">Creat My Work</button>` is not giving any.

Also

```
var numOfRect = parseInt(document.getElementById("inSquer").value);
var numOfCirc = parseInt(document.getElementById("inCircle").value);
```

does not exactly do anything, as the values are empty when that code runs.

Try changing the paint function like so:

```
function paint() 
{

    var numOfRect = parseInt(document.getElementById("inSquer").value);
    var numOfCirc = parseInt(document.getElementById("inCircle").value);

    for (var makeIt = 0; makeIt < numOfRect; makeIt++) 
    {
        makeRect(drawing, context);
        makeCircle(drawing, context);
    }
}
```

Comment: This did nothing. same result.

Comment: This portion is not the only thing broken with your code. I am trying to streer you into the right direction, not do your work.

Comment: No need to be a douche @Piwwoli it's also wrong to submit an answer to only answer a portion of the question in that case

Comment: @MeMyselfAndI Then again, it makes no sense to submit a question with completely broken code. I commented first, but comments are stupid hard to read so I made an answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the following snippet.

First of all, your `paint()` function was missing two arguments. Apart from that, I would recommend to define all the variables on top of your script, so it's easier to keep track.

I have added a few comments in the code to highlight the changes.

Also I have removed a few redundant DOM interactions.

```js
// Wait for DOM to be loaded.
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  
  // Keep references to elements, so we could interact with them later.
  var drawing = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var context = drawing.getContext("2d");
  var inSquer = document.getElementById("inSquer");
  var inCircle = document.getElementById("inCircle");
  var button = document.getElementById("creat");

  // Attach event listeners to the button and canvas element.
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {

    // Retrieve values from input fields every time you click.
    paint(parseInt(inSquer.value), parseInt(inCircle.value));
  });

  drawing.addEventListener("click", function() {
    saveImage();
  });

  // Function to save the canvas as an image.
  function saveImage() {
    window.location = drawing.toDataURL("image/png");
  }

  // This function will draw on the canvas.
  function paint(numOfRect, numOfCirc) {

    for (var makeIt = 0; makeIt < numOfRect; makeIt++) {
      makeRect(drawing, context);
      makeCircle(drawing, context);
    }
  }

  // This function draw the circles.
  function makeCircle(drawing, context) {

    var radius = Math.floor(Math.random() * 80);
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height);

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    context.fillStyle = "blue";
    context.fill();
  }

  // This function draw the squers.
  function makeRect(drawing, context) {

    var w = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height);

    context.fillStyle = "yellow";
    context.fillRect(x, y, w, w);
  }
});
```

```css
#canvas {
  margin-left: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1200" height="750"></canvas>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <span>
    How many Circles do you want?
    <input id="inCircle" />
    </span>
  <br/>How many Squers do you want?
  <input id="inSquer" />
  <br/>
  <button id="creat">Creat My Work</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Im following on what you wrote here, and i can understand what you did. ive tried to just copy and past your code to see how it work on my pc, but it wont run/work. but when i press the "run code snippet" on this site, it does. can you tell me why your code wont run on my pc? (im running it in notepad++).

Comment: @GabrielMichaeli Most likely you're injecting the script in `<head>`, it willl won't work like that. I have updated the script with `DOMContentLoaded` event listener, so it will wait until DOM is loaded, alternatively you might try using `load` event.

Comment: I see. Oh, man... I don't know how to use this. Can you please tell me how to run it in the normal-basic way in <head>? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @GabrielMichaeli if you have a separate javascript file, that you include with a `<script>` tag in `<head>` then you have to make your script to wait until the DOM is loaded. Check [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) for the reference. Alternatively you might include your script at the very bottom of the `<body>`, so it will be executed only when everything else is loaded. Here's also a basic reference with examples [JavaScript - Placement in HTML File](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_placement.htm)

Comment: I will follow on it. Thanks. Sorry for the noob Questions.

Comment: @GabrielMichaeli You're welcome, always happy to help. Please join the [SO Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript) if you will have any follow-up questions. There are plenty of super-cool people.